# How can i get many details as possible about error using React Error boundry get error details?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, error-handling, react-error-boundary

Im tring to catch more details when error accuring.

when the error is accuring im using node api server to catch the error and save in log file.

i simulated a Network Error and tring to get many details as possible.

when i console.log the error in frontend im getting this:

```
 withFormHandler.js:28 Uncaught Error: Error: Network Error
    at Object.componentDidUpdate (withFormHandler.js:28)
    ...
```

but i cant send this information using my api.
all im getting in the server side is an empty object.

so how can i catch and send many details as possible about the error and write it to the log file?

this is my ErrorBoundry component:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hasError: false,
    error: { message: "", stack: "" },
    info: { componentStack: "" },
   };

  static getDerivedStateFromError = (error) => {
    return { hasError: true };
   };

 componentDidCatch = (error, info) => {
    this.setState({ error, info });
    axios
    .get(`http://localhost:5001/api/logs/error`, {
      params: {
      error: error.message,
      details: info,
      // details:error  ---> this is also not give me information i need
      },
    })
   .catch(() => {});
 };

 render() {
   const { hasError, error, info } = this.state; 
   const { children } = this.props;
   return hasError ? <ErrorComponent message={error.message} /> : children;
  }
}
```

this is the server side handle:

```
 router.get("/error", (req, res) => {
   const errorMessage = req.query.error;
   const details = req.query.details;   -----> return an empty object :(
   const logFile = "./logs/debug.log";
       if (errorMessage) {
          let error = errorMessage + "\r\n" + details;
          fs.appendFile(logFile, error, function (err) {
           // callback or something
      });
    }
 });
```